# How to reproduce each time the same results with tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, random-seed

I'm using a RL algorithm (PPO with tensorflow.keras) and my problem is that for each train/test I got different results. Therefore, I don't know if the small changes that I make for the agent are indeed better or just random. I know that I have to set a seed. I'm using the following code that I run only in main.py:

```
def set_seeds(seed):
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

    os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
    os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'
    tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
    tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

Is there anything else that I need to set? This function is not working.

Comment: Do you have a specific error message or result you're getting? This code is not enough the answer your question. Your code should work I think.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.